# MySQL Boolean search with wildcard character not working

Tags: mysql, sql, search, boolean, full-text-search

I have used MySql Boolean search mode on a table using "FULLTEXT" key on value. I am using ENGINE=MyISAM.

When I search for a value say 16-ASDF using 16* it is not returning me in result .
Where as if I I have value 16ASDF it is returned when I search using 16*

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
my_search ms 
WHERE MATCH (ms.value) AGAINST ('16*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY ms.id LIMIT 100
```

It returns result where values are like **1612345**, or **16asdf** but no result is returned for rows having value **16-asdf** or **16-xxxx**

Can anyone please let me know why it is happening?

Comment: how to search using 16*, I don't understand?

Comment: show you  real code ..